# Scheduled internet disconnection

Tags: networking

I have a TG585n Thomson modem for my ADSL internet connection, and would like to schedule a daily internet disconnection at around 10pm till the morning to force children to go to bed :)

So I made a visual basic tool that runs putty, telnet to the modem, shutdown all physical interfaces, do mac address filtration and disallow all -but me- from internet access.

The problem is that I have to do this manually every day. So I'm wondering if there is any modem/router than has a feature to schedule the above (or at least schedule internet disconnection) on a daily basis.

If Linksys or any other modems can do that, that's great. I'm even willing to buy some enterprise grade router (like Cisco) if they can do this task.

Please advise.

Comment: You seem to be asking about product recommendations which would fall outside the scope of SU try rephrasing your question. I would look into solutions such as WRT-DD, ect... for this level of control without resorting to much more expensive routers

Comment: Why not just schedule the VBS to run via Windows' Task Scheduler?

Comment: DD-WRT or another custom firmware would definitely be the easiest and cheapest way to go about doing something like this. Just need to make sure you have, or purchase, a router that's compatible with DD-WRT.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're over complicating this. If you have a router, you can assign the kid's computers/phones/tablets to a specific IP Address Range based on the MAC Address of those devices. Set within your router, a Block Service of port 80 and 443 (and whatever else traffic ports) and select the IP Range of your kids devices.

[image]

In your Schedule section, set it to block every day from whatever times you specify.

[image]

My router (stock firmware) has this feature built into it. Instead of trying to create custom scripts that would affect the entire house, look to see what your router's capabilities are or purchase one with the capabilities. If you have an older router, you may be able to install a custom firmware that would have these features.

In my opinion, it is best to attack your situation this route as it will not cause you to lose internet access, just your kids. If you happen to share a common computer, you may be out of luck, but could handle similar things through software on that machine if you use different user accounts.

Comment: To add a side comment, my ISP provided me this router. I didn't end up paying anything for it. It is the Netgear WNDR3700V2 and is a few years old already.

Comment: Late to the party... but @kobaltz, I've tried this and got confused; I added an ip and the computer in question couldn't connect (even after reboot).. although I might try again. Either way, when you set up this "block services", then how do make sure that the "schedule" is just for THAT "block services"?